# Which library for parallel for-loops that iterate 1M*1k times, OpenMP or boost::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, boost-thread

I want to iterate an image pixel by pixel and do a 1000 of floating point operations per pixel. **Do you think I should use multi-threading or multiprocessing, i.e. boost::thread or OpenMP for this? Is there a rule of thumb to choose between these 2 (for fastest speed)?** I have understood that creating threads or switching between threads is multiple times faster than creating/switching processes. On the other hand implementing OpenMP code is much easier.

My solution right now:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(size_t i=0; i<640; ++i) {
    for(size_t j=0; j<480; ++j) {
        // do 1000 float operations
    }
}
```

Comment: if you use vs 2012 magic might be done by compiler:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872235.aspx

Comment: No, I don't use VS. Looking for a portable solution.

Comment: If *at all* possible, you want to use something that'll run on the GPU such as OpenCL, CUDA or a shader (GLSL or HLSL). For an operation like this, you can *expect* it to be something like 100x faster than the best you can hope to accomplish on the CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenMP is more than sufficient for this, in fact boost does not even have a built-in parallel loop construct.

> Do you think I should use multi-threading or multiprocessing

Although OpenMP stands for Open MultiProcessing, it is in fact a multithreading library.

An alternative library worth looking at is Intel TBB.

Comment: @lahjaton_j: No problem. Don't forget that you can mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem.